# Glide taking a long time to load large images from the web into a recyclerview

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-glide

I'm implementing a RecyclerView with a grid layout where in each grid element there is an ImageView in which Glide should load an image taken from and API.

The API returns images of varying dimensions but mostly lage files, and gives the following information about each image:

- width and height
- size and format (jpg/png)
- original size url
- thumbnail size url

The thumbnail is way too low quality to be used.
It allows me to filter for under or above a specific resolution, but if I do that I end up missing on the most interesting images. I want to be able to download a compressed version of any image, can glide do that? Is there a workaround to speed up the loading of such big images?

I tought of allowing better quality of wifi networks but I would like to cover all cases. Thanks.

Comment: There is no workaround to magically speed up the image download. Your API should start serving images also in other size or formats (WebP for instance). A that point once you load a low-res image you can still try to download the high-res and swap it if needed.